# zoom function not working properly on google maps on a django powered website

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

I am using google maps in my django powered web app, it works fine except when i try to zoom in or out, after a little bit it does not refresh and everything on the map goes blank. I guess it should be the javascript code, but I am not sure. Do you have any idea where the problem is?

**html file:**

```
{% extends "heaven/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

    {% block content %}
    <h2>Location of Cemetery</h2>
        <div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:500px;background:yellow">
        <script>
            function myMap() {
              var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
              var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng({{ cemetery.latitude }}, {{ cemetery.longitude }})
              var mapOptions = {center: myLatLng, zoom: 20};
              var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng});
              marker.setMap(map);
            }
        </script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You forgot to close <div> tag, should be `<div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:500px;background:yellow"></div>` .. maybe that's causing the issues?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I closed the div, but it was not the issue. The problem should be about google maps api. When I zoom, the map does not refresh itself

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was the second script tag that I had it also in the base template and once I removed it zooming in or out refreshes the map/tiles etc